# how to invoke a function in user login and logout in CAS

Tags: java, cas, jasig

i am using CAS for my application.i want to write an explicit function while successful authentication of user and also when user logout..how to do that one..can any one pls tell me..thanks in advance..

Comment: Welcome! More details are needed, are you using the spring framework in your application? Anyways: you can search for filters, interceptors or event mechanisms, which could be used in your case.

Comment: thanku for your reply.i am using spring.can you pls tell me how to add function with some example or pls provide any link to configure.

Answer (score 0):

To handle authentication success you need to implement an `ApplicationListener` - that is a spring bean, which implements `ApplicationListener` - [read the spring docs for more an event mechanism](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-events) and listens for `AuthenticationSuccessEvent`. Basically spring can publish events, that subscribed beans can handle. (Observer pattern)

To handle logout you can set the [`LogoutSuccessHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutSuccessHandler.html) in the `LogoutFilter`. [See Javadocs API from LogoutFilter.](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/index.html)

Comment: Thanku for you post..it helped me alot.but when successful authentication occured,even then onApplicationEvent is invoking but AuthenticationSuccessEvent is not invoking..what i have to do..please help me